# How to override Any parameter in Kotlin with Java Object?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm writing a retrofit implementation and I have the following interface method:

```
suspend fun uploadAvatar(file: Any, sessionToken: String)
```

In my impelementation I'm trying to override the 'file' parameter as a MultipartBody.Part object:

```
override suspend fun uploadAvatar(file: MultipartBody.Part, sessionToken: String)
```

and I'm getting the following error:

[image: error message]

I can see that okhttp3 is written in Java and I'm assuming that's the reason for the error. If so how do I get around it? Otherwise what else could be going on?

Answer (score 2):

It's not because it's written in Java. It's because you're trying to violate the interface contract by narrowing the type of an input parameter. The interface declares that `file` can be anything because it is of type Any. If the compiler let you narrow a type definition, then your class would be able to call functions specific to `MultipartBody.Part` on `file`, but then pass an instance of your class as the interface type, and some other code could pass a different class type to your function as `file`, which doesn't make sense.

I can't suggest how to avoid this problem because you didn't say how you're using your interface. I don't see what it really has to do with Retrofit.

In general, this kind of problem might be solved using generics, but that would only apply to some use cases. Example:

```
interface Foo<in T> {
    suspend fun uploadAvatar(file: T, sessionToken: String)
}

class MyFooBodyImpl: Foo<MultipartBody.Part> {
    suspend fun uploadAvatar(file: MultipartBody.Part, sessionToken: String) {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that will actually work for my usecase. The implementation is just a post call using Retrofit and I'm also going to use the interface for a mock implementation as a dependency during testing. I'm trying to conform to a clean architecture and from what I understand, I should be keeping the interfaces and implementations as independent as possible. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It can be good. Personal opinion: sometimes people get too dogmatic about “clean architecture” and ultimately create more work for themselves. Depends on the scale of the project I guess, and the nature of the unit tests related to the class/interface in question.

Comment: So unfortuantely I won't be able to use generics in my implementation because Retrofit needs to know the type at compile time: [source](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/885). It's a pretty old issue and I haven't found much else on the subject, but given what you said, I think I'm going to take an easier route even if it does break architecture a little bit.